# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() exception while running exe

Tags: java, ioexception, runtime.exec

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RunExternalExe {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\aaaa.exe, E:\\aaaaa.msi, E:\\aaaaa.mst");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("\n\n\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get this exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\aaaaaa.exe,E:\aaaaaaa.msi,E:\aaaaaa.mst": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at csvwriter.RunExternalExe.main(RunExternalExe.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

But the command `E:\aaaaa.exe,E:\aaaaa.msi,E:\aaaaa.mst` worksfine.

The exe file is a cpp file build in release mode.

Comment: Uhm, the commas are very probably the problem here. And why don't you use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Could you please post the code while it run using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: yes. it worked for me. Now no error is showing. thanks. :)

Comment: @1355, post your solution, can be useful for others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
             String  commands [] = new String [] {
           "CMD.EXE",
           "/C",
          "RUNAS /profile  /savecred /user:"
          + "administrator"
          + " " + "regedit.exe"
          };
```

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);